# What do you call a person who suggests ideas?

Tags: single-word-requests

Sorry if it has already been asked, but what do you call someone who **gives ideas/suggestions**? At a business meeting or a group discussion, for example.

Comment: Do you mean an employee of the company?  Or an outside person brought in for that purpose?

Comment: @childofsoong An employee of the company, to be specific.

Comment: That's an "idea person", if the suggestions are frequent and reasonably on-target.  This is a commonly-used descriptor in US business.

Comment: Uninspiring though it may seem, in everyday usage this is simply a "contributor" or a "participant." Especially in a meeting where ideas are directly solicited, sharing them is the intended contribution or form of participation. No need for a fancy word.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One of my pet hates, but no-one said that neologisms are unacceptable even if I'd scrub out my mouth with wire wool rather than use this one in real speech:

**Ideator**

> A person who creates productive ideas, a conceptualist
>
> One who ideates; one who holds or generates an idea, or synthesizes a concept

https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Ideator

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ideator

---

*"Ideation". I ask you. Mutter, mutter, grumble.*

Comment: This sounds to me like a non-gender-specific version of "idea man/woman" which I was thinking of. Thanks for expanding my vocabulary (even if you hate the word)!

Answer (score 6):

Idea Woman

[idea man](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/idea%20man)

> a person with an unusual capacity for visualizing and formulating new techniques, approaches, products (MW)

Answer (score 3):

I'd call such a person an [***innovator***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/innovator).

> A person who introduces new methods, ideas, or products.
>   *‘he was one of the great innovators in jazz’*

Reference:
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/innovator

Answer (score 2):

One who suggests could be called a *proposer*, *nominator*, or *advocate*.  I suggest or propose that we elect someone to provide a denotation for one who suggests.

Answer (score 1):

In group dynamics, a **Plant**.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Role_Inventories#Plant

> Plants are creative, unorthodox and generators of ideas. If an
>   innovative solution to a problem is needed, a Plant is a good person
>   to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Someone who suggests an idea could be called a **suggester**. The word is attested in the OED, but as it is subscriber only, you shall have to take my word for its existence.

Answer (score 0):

What about 'advisor '

Meaning from Google dictionary : a person who gives advice in a particular field.

And also 'counsellor' : an experienced and trusted adviser